# C++ circular dependency: What should the constructor look like?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

I read through a lot of circular dependency topics but all of them seem to be concerned with the declaration. I am interested how to construct the mutually depended objects and if there are potential pitfalls with my approach. Consider this simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A; //Forward declaration

class B{
    public:
        B(string name, A* a):myA(a), name(name){
            cout << "Works with pointer" << endl;
        };
    private:
        A* myA;
        string name;

};

class A{
    public:
        A(){
            cout << "Constructing A" << endl;
            if(bs.empty()) cout << "Vector is empty" << endl;
            bs.push_back(B("First", this));
            cout << "Array has " << bs.size() << " elements." << endl;
        };
    private:
        std::vector<B> bs;
};


int main() {
    cout << "Start" << endl;
    A a;
    cout << "Ok." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is there anything that I could do to avoid the `A*` pointer in `B`?

Ideally I would like to have a reference, but if I change the constructor of `B` to `B(string name, A& a)` and then change the push_back to `bs.bush_back(B("First", *this));` I get an error: `non-static reference member 'A& B::myA', can't use default assignment operator`. [See the modified example](https://gist.github.com/1084255)

As far as I can tell the `operator=` that is synthesized by the compiler does not fit here. How would the proper `operator=` look like? Or am I going the wrong direction all together?

Comment: If you have circular dependency, then you should remove it, not look for more workarounds.

Comment: Hmm, my (language-agnostic) domain model has circular dependencies. Is there any way I could work around the problem on a class design level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a type in a standard container, like `vector` the type needs to be *CopyConstructible* and *Assignable*. If your type has pointer members then these will work fine with an implicitly defined copy assignment operator but this is not the case with reference members as references can't be rebound.

If you want your type to work in a container it is much simpler to stick with pointer members. It's not obvious whether you can define a copy assignment operator that makes sense in your particular case, in general it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use a reference there even with a user-defined assignment-operator, because references cannot be rebound once they are initialized. Using a pointer here is the simplest approach.

Answer (score 0):

In this case (and *only* in this case), you could consider making `B` a template..

```
template <typename SomeA>
class B{
    public:
        B(string name, SomeA& a):myA(a), name(name){
            cout << "Works with reference" << endl;
        };
    private:
        boost::optional<SomeA&> myA;
        string name;
};

class A{
    public:
        A(){
            cout << "Constructing A" << endl;
            if(bs.empty()) cout << "Vector is empty" << endl;
            bs.push_back(B<A>("First", *this));
            cout << "Array has " << bs.size() << " elements." << endl;
        };
    private:
        std::vector<B<A> > bs;
};
```

This suggestion is purely without any context...

Comment: How will that help? `B<A>` still contains a reference, and so is still not assignable.

Comment: @Mike, aww crap, I only partially answered - I did not think at all about the fact that `B<A>` is held in vector... fixed now..